# Group by unique Name and Status with the last Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, crosstab

I would like to analyze statistics per cars which were repairs and which are new. Data sample is:

```
Name   IsItNew    ControlDate
Car1    True      31/01/2018
Car2    True      28/02/2018
Car1    False     15/03/2018
Car2    True      16/04/2018
Car3    True      30/04/2018
Car2    False     25/05/2018
Car1    False     30/05/2018
```

So, I should `groupby` by Name and if there is a `False` in `IsItNew` column I should set `False` and the first date, when `False` was happened.

I tried `groupby` with `nunique()`:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','IsItNew', 'ControlDate' ])['Name'].nunique()
```

But, it returns count of unique items in each group.

How can I receive only grouped unique items without any count?

```
Actual result is:

Name   IsItNew       ControlDate
Car1    True         31/01/2018     1
        False        15/03/2018     1
                     30/05/2018     1
Car2    True         28/02/2018     1
                     16/04/2018     1
        False        25/05/2018     1 
Car3    True         30/04/2018     1


Expected Result is:

Name   IsItNew     ControlDate
Car1    False      15/03/2018
Car2    False      25/05/2018
Car3    True       30/04/2018
```

I'd appreciate for any idea. Thanks)

Comment: If add next row  `Car3    True      01/05/2017` then in output is `30/04/2018` or `30/04/2018` for `Car3` ?

Comment: if we add ```Car3``` with ```True```and ```01/05/2017``` Date then result for ```True``` values should be last date ```30/04/2018```, not first one as for ```False```. So, correct behavior is last actual date for ```True``` and first one for ```False``` value

Comment: Please check edited answer.

Comment: @jezrael, theoretically, correct behavior will be ```20/10/2019``` date for Car3, because it shows the end actual status of Car3. If compare it with current date today(28/03/2019), than ```20/10/2019``` is future. Also, Date ```30/04/2017``` is date, when Car3 firstly appears in dataset and after the next item for Car3 set under 30/04/2018. I understand that you mean what happens if the column with ControlDate will not be sorted and contains future date.. Does it make sense?

Comment: So solution working like expected? If all Trues, get last True, else first False per groups.

Comment: yes, suggested solution works as expected. All right, Thanks)

Comment: Firstly, I took the first suggested solution. When I run it for more than 60 K rows, the question about time execution was happened. I estimated the time of executing the suggested query from your comment and results are: ```--- 0.5322470664978027 seconds ---```, the second query is executed during ```--- 68.36492991447449 seconds ---``` That's why I changed the accepted answer of current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then sorting by 3 columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last get first row by column `Name`s by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['ControlDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ControlDate'])

df = df.sort_values(['Name','IsItNew', 'ControlDate']).drop_duplicates('Name')

print (df)
   Name  IsItNew ControlDate
2  Car1    False  2018-03-15
5  Car2    False  2018-05-25
4  Car3     True  2018-04-30
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   Name  IsItNew ControlDate
0  Car1     True  31/01/2018
1  Car2     True  28/02/2018
2  Car1    False  15/03/2018
3  Car2     True  16/04/2018
4  Car3     True  30/04/2018
5  Car2    False  25/05/2018
6  Car1    False  30/05/2018
7  Car3     True  20/10/2019
8  Car3     True  30/04/2017

#set to datetimes
df['ControlDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ControlDate'])
#sorting by 3 columns
df1 = df.sort_values(['Name','IsItNew', 'ControlDate'])

#create Series for replace
s = df1.drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last').set_index('Name')['ControlDate']

#filter by Falses
df2 = df1.drop_duplicates('Name').copy()
#replace True rows by last timestamp
df2.loc[df2['IsItNew'], 'ControlDate'] = df2.loc[df2['IsItNew'], 'Name'].map(s)
print (df2)
   Name  IsItNew ControlDate
2  Car1    False  2018-03-15
5  Car2    False  2018-05-25
8  Car3     True  2019-10-20
```

Comment: @@jezrael, thank you so much for great idea! It works as needed.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to `GroupBy` the `Name`, and aggregate on `IsItNew` with two functions. A custom one using `any` to check if there are any `False` values, and [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html), to find the index of the first `False`, which you can later on use to index the dataframe on `ControlDate`:

```
df_ = df.groupby('Name').agg({'IsItNew':
                                   {'IsItNew':lambda x: ~(~x).any(),
                                    'ControlDate':'idxmin'}})
                        .droplevel(0, axis=1)
                        .reset_index()

df_['ControlDate'] = df.loc[df_['ControlDate'].values, 'ControlDate'].reset_index(drop=True)

  xName  IsItNew ControlDate
0  Car1    False  15/03/2018
1  Car2    False  25/05/2018
2  Car3     True  30/04/2018
```

Comment: I think because performance with datetimes is better like min of strings.

Comment: ya, just think both solution should be good, it depends what op need.

Comment: @yatu Thank you so much for your solution. It also works as needed, but the time of execution for table with more than 60K rows is ```--- 68.36492991447449 seconds ---``` if compare with previous idea (where the time is ```0.5322470664978027 sec```)